# Firefox bookmark editor

Tags: macos, firefox, bookmarks

Safari auto edits bookmarks such that the  **https://** and  **.com/...** are cut off, so that one can see the book mark name without all the gak.

And one can still further edit the left hand (name) column if one desires.
is there something like that for Firefox?

---

**Update from comments:** macOS Sierra. Firefox 68.02.

And to be clearer, I'm not looking for info how to save new bookmarks. I have older bookmarks that I imported from Safari or Google Chrome. These appear in the Bookmarks editor of Firefox as "https://" on both sides of the editor, Name and Location. I'm trying to reformat the left side (Name) to Names without the prefix and suffix.

Comment: What OS and Firefox version are you referencing?

Comment: I suppose that would have been helpful info, huh?
OSX Sierra.  FFx 68.02.

And to be clearer, I'm not looking for info how to save new bookmarks.

I have older bookmarks that I imported from Sierra or Chrome.
These appear in the Bookmarks editor of FFx as https:// on both sides of the editor, Name and Location.
I'm trying to reformat the left side (Name) to Names without the prefix and suffix.